# Problema al llamar JQUERY desde Servidor Linux

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en donde se llama a jquery a través de la siguiente ruta:

```
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"
```

Mi problema es que al cargar el archivo en mi servidor, no muestra parte del contenido de la pagina.

Hice un ping y llego a la ruta ajax.googleapis.com pero la query no es detectada.

Comment: Gracias por responder, descargue un sistema repositorio de archivos desde la pagina https://github.com/configuroweb/manejadordearchivos, cuando ocupo el link de jquery desde Internet funciona bien en mi PC pero no en e servidor donde tengo mi pagina

Comment: Lo de las versiones de JQUERY no entiendo mucho, soy nuevo programando, agradecería si me comentas que otra versión mas reciente me podría funcionar

Comment: Cuando hago un pin desde el servidor a la pagina de la Query llego sin problemas, pero desde el sistema no logro que detecte la query, sabes porque puede ser??

Comment: Revise la consola y no muestra ningún error

Comment: ¿Entonces, qué te hace pensar que el problema es causado por jQuery?

Comment: Porque en mi PC si funciona y cuando le elimino el código de la JQUERY pasa lo mismo que en el servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para facilitar las cosas podrías consumir Jquery desde un CDN por ejemplo el siguiente es de google
[mirrors](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El problema que estás teniendo actualmente es con tus rutas, deberías investigar acerca de rutas relativas y absolutas.

Si estás trabajando con un servidor en [UNIX](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/#:%7E:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20defined%20as%20specifying%20the%20location%20of,actual%20file%20system%20from%20%2F%20directory.&text=Relative%20path%20is%20defined%20as,present%20working%20directly(pwd)) y si no en [WINDOWS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)